# Making a container appear with a button after making it disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I click on a `div` container (it disappears) and another one appears with a button. Then, I want to go back to the previous `div` container using a button made-up of a `div` container (keep in mind that I only want to perform this action in the `currentTarget`).

I only want to do this to the current container or the one clicked on!

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.shown').on('click', event => {
      $(event.currentTarget).next('.tab').show();
      $(event.currentTarget).hide();
    });

    $('.button').on('click', event => {
      /*i want to hide the container with class tab and show the container with class shown*/
    });
});
```

```css
.shown {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.con {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main {
  width: auto;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.tab {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.button {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px dotted white;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="con">
    <div class="shown">

    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>One</p>
      <div class="button">Show</div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="con">
    <div class="shown">

    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Two</p>
      <div class="button">Show</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="con">
    <div class="shown">

    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Three</p>
      <div class="button">Show</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
    
    
    
    $('.shown').on('click',event=>{
      $(event.currentTarget).next('.tab').show();
      $(event.currentTarget).hide();
    });
    
    $('.button').on('click',event=>{
     /*i want to hide the container with class tab and show the container with class shown*/
          $('.tab').hide();
          $('.shown').show();
     
    });
    

   });
```

```css
.shown{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
   }
   
   .con{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
   }
   .main{
    width: auto;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
   }
   
   .tab{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: none;
   }
   
   p{
    display: inline-block;
   }
   
   .button{
    width: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px dotted white;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
   <div class="con">
    <div class="shown">
     
    </div>
    <div class="tab"><p>One</p>
     <div class="button">Show</div>
     
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main"> 
   <div class="con">
    <div class="shown">
     
    </div>
    <div class="tab"><p>Two</p>
     <div class="button">Show</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main">
   <div class="con">
    <div class="shown">
     
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
     <p>Three</p>
     <div class="button">Show</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That works, but i only want to hide container in which is clicked on

Comment: i was thinking of something like:                    
        $('.button').on('click',event=>{
          $(event.currentTarget).prev().hide();
          $(event.currentTarget).prev().show();
  //Although this doesn't work   
    });